# $cordovaCamera adds black background to transparent PNG

Tags: cordova, camera, base64, transparency, cordova-plugins

Plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

```
var options = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  allowEdit: true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
  targetWidth: 128,
  targetHeight: 128,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};
```

I am able to successfully get the ImageURI with this but the problem is when I'm selecting PNG file with transparent background, it becomes black. If it helps, I'm converting the imageURI into a blob.

```
imageUri = "data:image/png;base64," + imageData;

  dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
      array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
      type: mimeString
    });
  };
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Any of you guys found a solution?